# How to iterates over a List<T> base class within the child class?

Tags: c#, list, inheritance, ienumerable, enumerable

I have a collection class that inherits List. I would like a method on that class that can iterate over the items in the base class list.

Currently I have this:

```
    public class Invoices : List<Invoice>
    {
        public string ToString()
        {
            string cOP = "";
            int i;
            Invoice oInvoice;

            cOP += string.Format("Invoices.Count = {0}\r\n", base.Count);

            foreach (Invoice oInvoice in base)
            {
                cOP += oInvoice.ToString();
            }

            return cOP;
        }
    }
```

But I get the compile time error on base in the foreach statement, "Use of keyword 'base' is not valid in this context".

I've tried replacing base with:

- base.ToArray() - this does work, but I thought the whole point of a List is that it is enumerable.
- base.ToList() - "'System.Collections.Generic.List<SerializerTest.Invoice>' does not contain a definition for 'ToList'"

Is there a reason why I need to convert the List to an Array to iterate over it? Surely I should just be able to iterate over the List?

Comment: Here's a tip for you, inheriting from `List<T>` is a bad practice.

Comment: Use `this` instead of `base`? (Note: MS Guidelines say you should inherit from `Collection<T>` rather than `List<T>`)

Comment: `foreach (Invoice oInvoice in this)` however your class is fairly munted, as stated don't inherit lists, implement collection interfaces

Comment: [Why not inherit from List<T>?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21692193/982149)

Comment: In Eric Lipperts words: "Do you want to extend the List<T> mechanism or do you want to create a business object that needs a collection"? I'm sure you want the latter, so make it a property in your class.

Comment: Tim is absolutely correct - you should [prefer composition over inheritance](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/134097/why-should-i-prefer-composition-over-inheritance)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use the `this` keyword:

```
public class Invoices : List<Invoice>
{
    public string ToString()
    {
        string cOP = "";
        int i;
        Invoice oInvoice;

        cOP += string.Format("Invoices.Count = {0}\r\n", base.Count);

        foreach (Invoice oInvoice in this)
        {
            cOP += oInvoice.ToString();
        }

        return cOP;
    }
}
```

Comment: While this answer will make it work, be aware that inheriting `List<T>` is not the best of ideas in the first place.

Comment: For future readers, although this solves the problem, this is not the appropriate solution. Please read the comments under the question

Comment: Thanks both. I wasn't aware that inheriting List was a bad design. The class above is simply part of a test project to experiment with serialization so no major harm done. I'll bear that in mind. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a more usual approach

```
public class Invoices : IEnumerable<Invoice>
{
   private readonly List<Invoice> _invoices = new List<Invoice>();

   public IEnumerator<Invoice> GetEnumerator() => _invoices.GetEnumerator(); 
   IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() => GetEnumerator();

   public override string ToString()
   {
      var sb = new StringBuilder();

      sb.AppendLine($"Invoices.Count = {_invoices.Count}");

      foreach (var oInvoice in _invoices)
         sb.Append(oInvoice);

      return sb.ToString();
   }  
}
```

Just add the methods you need. If you need more list type methods, implement `ICollection` or `IList`

Comment: Thanks, dude, you made me search for performance/design considerations of inheriting a List. I mostly found it as a design issue, not performance. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21692193/why-not-inherit-from-listt  Anyway, thanks a lot.